# Visual Studio (C#) после сборки удаляет все комментарии

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

столкнулся такой маленькой проблемой, есть проект под dll в коде есть ряд комментариев описывающие что делает тот или иной метод или свойствы и.д, так вот после компиляции,открыв другой проект и добавив ссылку на свою dll,я решил проверить и обнаружил что этих комментариев нет. Если способ сказать Visual Studio не удалять все комментарии?

P.S: Я честно искал ответы тут на форуме, может кто то уже задавал ранее вопросы но так и не нашёл тут.

Моя версия VS 2017 если что.

Comment: Вы используете xml-комментарии?

Comment: Я использую так:
        /// <summary>
        /// Test
        /// </summary>
        public float test;

Comment: Может оно их не удаляет, а просто сворачивает? Там слева от текста нет плюсика в квадрате?

Comment: Он есть, я да же сейчас посмотрел в программе ILSpy и там вообще ничего нет,

Comment: Просто нажмите на этот плюсик - комментарий раскроется.  Но зачем ilspy - Вы комментарии смотрите в скомпилированном коде?

Comment: @KoVadim Тут есть 2 скриншота, [Первый](https://github.com/ARtronClassicStudio/Chat-room/blob/44ac53690d3ad9ce7ec1f10c09cc2af6e427030d/1.PNG) и [Второй](https://github.com/ARtronClassicStudio/Chat-room/blob/44ac53690d3ad9ce7ec1f10c09cc2af6e427030d/2.PNG) ,  ilspy на всякий случай смотрю если что то не так (привычка).

Comment: Открыть свойства (Properties) проекта в Visual Studio, вкладка Build, поставить чекбокс XML documentation file.

Comment: `ILSpy` смотрит `IL` код, этот код не может содержать комментарии, их там и быть не должно. Плмментарии предназначены только для разработки, при сборке они игнорируются. Это так работает. Комментарии могут идти как метаданные, отдельно от сборки. Еще вя можете подключать библиотеку не как бинарный файл, а как проект, тогда комменты будут доступны прямо из исходников.

Comment: Поиск на английском дает такой ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1632975/6468198

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, проблема решена: Открыть свойства (Properties) проекта в Visual Studio, вкладка Build, поставить чекбокс XML documentation file.